# How to get the pandas columns into rows with custom condition?

Tags: python, pandas

I have a dataframes like that

**df1**

```
  A   B   C      SN
0  10  23  48  456123
1  15  45  98  789456
2  16  62  55  123789
```

**df2**

```
    A   B     C      SN
0  10  19  48.0  456123
1  15  45   NaN  789456
2  68  77  55.0  123789
```

I need something like below

```
SN   123789  456123  789456
A_x    16    10    15
B_x    62    23    45
C_x    55    48    98
A_y    68    10    15
B_y    77    19    45
C_y    55    48     0
```

I have tried using pandas groupby and pivot but didn't working as I wanted. Any help?

Comment: What is expected output if first `SN` is changed in `df1` to `111` ? You need remove this row?

Comment: SN will not change to 111. it'll be around max 20.

Answer (score 1):

You can do something like this below.

```
output = pd.merge(df1,df2,on='SN').groupby(['SN']).sum().transpose()
```

output:

```
    SN   123789  456123  789456
A_x    16.0    10.0    15.0
B_x    62.0    23.0    45.0
C_x    55.0    48.0    98.0
A_y    68.0    10.0    15.0
B_y    77.0    19.0    45.0
C_y    55.0    48.0     0.0
```

Later you can change the type to int from float.

Comment: Why aggregate `sum` ?

Comment: Sir, did I do any mistake?

Comment: hmmm, I think groupby here is not necessary, also not sure if want OP inner join? Question is a bit unclear.

Comment: thank you sir, you have been doing a great work. I just started exploring things need to learn alot from people like you  :-)

Answer (score 1):

Use [`merge`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.merge.html) with replace `0` by [`fillna`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.fillna.html), if necessary [`sort_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.sort_index.html) and trne transpose by [`set_index`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.set_index.html) with [`T`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.DataFrame.T.html):

```
#if need inner join
df3 = dfa.merge(df2,on='SN').fillna(0).sort_index().set_index('SN').T
#if need outer join
df3 = dfa.merge(df2,on='SN', how='outer').fillna(0).sort_index().set_index('SN').T
print (df3)
SN   456123  789456  123789
A_x    10.0    15.0    16.0
B_x    23.0    45.0    62.0
C_x    48.0    98.0    55.0
A_y    10.0    15.0    68.0
B_y    19.0    45.0    77.0
C_y    48.0     0.0    55.0
```

Another solution with outer join with [`concat`](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.concat.html):

```
df3 = (pd.concat([df1.set_index('SN'), 
                  df2.set_index('SN')], axis=1, keys=('x', 'y')).T.fillna(0))

#flatten MultiIndex
df3.index = [f'{j}_{i}' for i, j in df3.index]
print (df3)
SN   456123  789456  123789
A_x    10.0    15.0    16.0
B_x    23.0    45.0    62.0
C_x    48.0    98.0    55.0
A_y    10.0    15.0    68.0
B_y    19.0    45.0    77.0
C_y    48.0     0.0    55.0
```